# Prevention duplicate value when insert data in list() in php

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to create a shopping basket in my project, but some problem to handle this. My project basket must allow duplicate value, but my code auto duplicate last insert to array. Why does this happen, and how to solve this auto duplicate?

more description:
this shopping product have any color and any meter and user can select any color for buy for facility buying i want to enable variuos color as one product for this work i make simple $key generator this multiple array (for To avoid re-writing to one key) but when insert data in array and change $key value , prviose data and new data plased in array

this php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['basket'])){
    $key = end((array_keys($_SESSION['basket'])));
    $key++;
}else{
    $key = 0;
    echo " count = 0";
}

    if(isset($_GET['id'] , $_GET['meter'] , $_GET['color'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];  

        $color = $_GET['color'];    

        $meter = $_GET['meter'];    

        $selected_product = array($id , $color , $meter);

        list($_SESSION['basket'][$key][0],$_SESSION['basket'][$key][1] , $_SESSION['basket'][$key][2]) = $selected_product;

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_SESSION['basket']);
        echo "</pre>";
        $count = count($_SESSION['basket']);
        echo " count = ".$count;
    }


?>
```

view array:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(3) { [2]=> string(4) "5544" [1]=> string(6) "green" [0]=> string(2) "11" }
[1]=> array(3) { [2]=> string(4) "5544" [1]=> string(6) "green" [0]=> string(2) "11" } 
[2]=> array(3) { [2]=> string(3) "234" [1]=> string(8) "black" [0]=> string(2) "10" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are trying to be way too fancy. Check your code again and make sure you understand what you are doing: First you create an array with all the properties of the shopping basket entry and then you disassemble the array and put all pieces one-by-one into the shopping basket. This is totally unnecessary.

You can assign entire arrays to be elements in another array:

```
$foo = array();
$foo['entry1'] = array(1, 2, 3);
$foo['entry2'] = array(2, 3, 4);
```

There is absolutely no need to use `list()`; get rid of it and keep it simple. Also, instead of messing around with a numeric key, you could just use [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) instead or the shorthand `$foo[]`, if you prefer.

And on another note: I would avoid using GET requests for actions. Use POST instead. If the user refreshes the shopping basket, they will always insert another product. GET requests should be used to *get* information, while POST should be used to *send* information.

Comment: tnx alot Till Helge
you can tell me how to change this code to you suggest?
sorry for poor english

Comment: @user3082533 I told you pretty much exactly what you need to do. If you can't make sense of it, I have to assume that you have no clue what your code actually does...which would mean that you are not looking for help with your code, but rather someone to write your code for you. This is not how SO works. Try yourself and ask again, if you encounter problems. Show some effort.